# mobileSDK support Xcode13 and iOS15?

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, ios

Target :

- SDK Name : mobileSDK SDK
- ver.: 8.1.0 (for iOS) ← This is the currently installed SDK version.

What I want to know :
(1) The public document (*1) says "Xcode version: 12 or later. ,Base SDK: iOS 14", does this mean that the latest version of mobileSDK (9.1.1) is not yet compatible with Xcode13 (iOS15)?
*1 https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/ios_requirements.htm

(2) If the answer to (1) is not yet supported, when do you plan to release a version that supports Xcode13?

(3) At the moment, we are developing our iOS app with Xcode 12.2 and mobileSDK 8.1, so the supported OS is iOS 12.2~.
If we keep the iOS deployment target:12.2 for our app, when we update from Xcode 12.2 to Xcode 13, do we also need to update the mobileSDK version from 8.1 to 9.1.1?

Answer (score 0):

We tried application on SFDC Hybrid Remote iOS App and wanted to test this with the new Xcode 13.0 Beta with iOS 15. However, we have a build issue and we are not able to run the application on XCode 13.0 / iOS 15 simulator. [image]

Comment: It is unclear to me whether this is an answer or another question. If this is an answer, please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/357741/edit) your answer to make it more clear as to how this answer addresses the question that was asked. If you are having the same or similar issue as the OP, please delete this answer and either [A] upvote or comment under the original question, or - if your issue is different enough, [B] please ask a new question (and link to the above question if desired). (Or [C] both A & B.)

Comment: This is not an answer, but I am also facing similar problem with the Salesforce SDK. I am not able to do either of the because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: You can certainly do [B] - you only need 1 reputation to ask a question. If you contribute to SFSE in other ways (e.g., editing, answering) in won't take you long to gain a litte reputation in order to do [A] - you only need 15 reputation to upvote, and 50 to comment everywhere.